# Cannot add custom css class to image

Tags: html, css

This code works correctly to change the image width to fit on a phone screen

css

```
img { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

html

```
<img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
```

But this affects all the other images in my page, so I want to set it to a custom class

Following online tutorials I tried setting it using

css

```
imglogo { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

html

```
<img class="imglogo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
```

I also tried:

css

```
.imglogo { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

html

```
<img class="imglogo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Lights" style="width:100%">
```

But the image did not recognize css for imglogo

What am I doing wrong?
And also what is the `.` in front the css class used for?

Thanks,

Comment: You need to remove `style="width:100%"` in the HTML and use a media query.

Comment: You forgot the period.  In css class selectors start with a period, so  ".imglogo" not "imglogo".

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable that you use an HTML "class" attribute for each one of your such images. Refer to your class in your spreadsheet when you want to make the changes. Another golden thumb rule is, Never make your tag properties and your CSS properties interfere.

What I am saying is that, when it comes to the styling of the page, put your required width and other edits on the CSS stylesheet and not inside the HTML tag.

Your CSS should read:

```
.image1 { width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

Your HTML should read:

```
<img class= "image1" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Lights">
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```css
.imglogo {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
}
```

```html
<img class="imglogo" src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Lights">
```

You can also try to put a !important after the width and height, please note, that this is not best practise:

```css
.imglogo {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important; 
}
```

If you included an external style sheet, please make sure that you've included it with the  `link` tag in the `head`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an extra file for your style, you might have forgotten to import the stylesheet to your HTML page. You can do that by adding a `<Link />` tag to the head of your HTML site. Besides that, the code looks correct to me.

I recommend having a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp

You can use the dot in CSS to access CSS-classes.